# Does Web Api app support integration(compatible) with ASP.Net and web services application, i.e. merging two IIS apps into one?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have two IIS applications, one is ASP.Net application (with some web services interfaces) another - Web Api IIS application.
I need simplify deployment and IT maintenance,  so I asked to merge these two IIS applications into single one.
I'm in doubt whether Web Api allows to to this? Are there any drawbacks or uncompatibili?

Comment: There is nothing called "WinApi IIS application". Did you invent it?

Comment: Sorry, 20 years of c++ Windows API programming made impact)  corrected.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms Can you check if cut and paste works as this article mentions?

Comment: Policy of this forum assumes answer.

Comment: I read link, thank you,it's plausible. usefull article. This time ms doc is more useful than oversimplified answer.

Comment: Additionally to link If somebody consider disadvantiges of such mix this would be good answer.